# RocketTab is uninstalled but still haunt me

Tags: command-line, boot, popups

Every time I start my computer a command prompt and window will pop up saying

> "Windows cannot find 'C:\Program Files (x86)\RocketTab\Client.exe'
>   Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again.".

I have already reset Chrome and Internet Explorer and used a malware cleaner to clean my system but this still appears every time I boot my computer. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: You need to manually remove the entry in your registry for RocketTab.

Answer (score 6):

**Issue:** AFTER successfully removing the 'RocketTab' malware (using a utility such as Malwarebytes Anti-malware), Windows starts up with a 'Command Prompt' (cmd.exe) appears and is shortly followed by an error message reading, "Windows cannot find c:\program files(x86)\rocket tab\client.exe".

**Resolution:** Open the 'C:\windows\system32\tasks' directory. Locate and delete all files containing the word 'Rocket'. IMPORTANT: DO NOT DELETE the RTKCPL file. This is a legitimate Windows file. Restart your computer. The error should not return.

Comment: Given Ross' answer, one might also be able to do this using the Task Scheduler GUI.

Comment: Unfortunately the Rocket entries were not listed in my Task Scheduler (Not sure Why???). However I found them in the directory as listed above and removed them manually which resolved my issue. Just thought I would pass this along...

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), which will let you disable startup items. Look for an entry that mentions RocketTab or Client.exe, then un-check it to prevent it from running at boot.

You can also right-click > Delete to remove it permanently.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Well even after uninstalling this software,  checking msconfig,  and deleting the file folder, I even checked my services to make sure it hadnt creating one as well,  nothing there.  I was getting the same issue as the OP stated.  Theres one thing here that you folks missed,  and I did at first.  I noticed the same issue as the op,  when you look at the issue,  the window that pops up on startup is taskeng.exe  Dawned on me that this little pos rocketab software had created a scheduled task.  So anyone who wants to rid themselves of this anoying issue at start up,  needs to go into your taskscheduler and disable the two rocketab entries,  and or delete them.  This will rid you of this anoying software.  Hope this helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Oh right, I just fixed this before answering this question. There are many tutorials on how to remove this (RocketTab), but only ads to browser, and cannot remove RocketTab Client from startup.

So SAVE THIS TO YOUR BRAIN!

We need to remove it from startup, but when we open "Msconfig" there is nothing or similar name with RocketTab. So again we need 3rd party application, in here we just use CCLeaner from Piriform(CCleaner you are the best for my problem XD). Download and install it, from Tools menu open tab Startup. And click tab once again in Scheduled Tasks.. u see Rockettab? Remove it, disable it, or anything you want to kill it.

Sorry for my bad english speak, victory is ours