# Im having trouble accessing the internet on my pc

Tags: windows-xp

How do I fix this problem??? I open my browser and it won't connect and shows up this message - (RocketTab) The socket connection to d2e24t2jgcnor2.webhostoid.com failed. A Firewall may be blocking RocketTab's traffic.
Errorcode: 10013.
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way that is forbidden by its access permissions 107.20.191.72:80

Comment: Please do Start ¦ Run ¦ cmd {Enter} . . to get to a Command Prompt then in that white letters-on-black window, do PING WWW.GOOGLE.COM {Enter} and please tell us the time in ms (milliseconds) for each attempt to connect. Please also advise if you were using Internet Explorer (blue lower case 'e' or a different Web browser.

Comment: Uninstall RocketTab, restart, and try again

Answer (score 1):

RocketTab claims to be a handy search enhancement for Chrome, IE, etc, but is just annoying adware. Try to remove it through the configuration panel/programs or through the add-on management of your browser. You can also try to remove it using [MalwareBytes Anti-Malware](https://www.malwarebytes.org/).
Note that it may also be named 'TabRocket'.

[Some people report that it's hard to remove](https://superuser.com/questions/805962/rockettab-is-uninstalled-but-still-haunt-me).

**And ask yourself how it got on your machine.** You probably installed some handy free software and juist clicked through all default buttons. Don't do that. **Always check what additional software gets installed**. You can often do that by choosing 'Custom setup' at the start of the installation; then you'll get more screens actually showing you what is going on.